# Find the limit of the following sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (\frac{1^{10} + 2^{10} + 3^{10} + ... + n^{10}}{n^{10}} - \frac{n}{11})$$

So I am aware that Stolz theorem may be used here but I don't know how. What I tried doing is I combined the two fractions:

$$ (\frac{11\dot(1^{10} + 2^{10} + 3^{10} + ... + n^{10}) - n^{11}}{11n^{10}})$$

But I can't apply Stolz theorem to this because we have two sequences in the numerator. Moreover the bigger problem is the $-$ sign next to $n^{11}$. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Faulhaber's formula ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^p= \frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1} + \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}} n^p + \text{lower order terms.}  
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

Let $ n\in\mathbb{N}^{*} $, $ f \in\mathscr{C}^{1}\left(\left[0,1\right],\mathbb{R}\right) $ be an increasing function, and $ F:\left[0,1\right]\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\ x\mapsto\int_{0}^{x}{f\left(y\right)\mathrm{d}y} $.

Denoting $ \left(\forall k\in\mathbb{N}\right),\ x_{k}=\frac{k}{n} \cdot $

\begin{aligned}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)}-\int_{0}^{1}{f\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x}&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\int_{x_{k}}^{x_{k-1}}{\left(f\left(x\right)-f\left(x_{k}\right)\right)\mathrm{d}x}}\\ &=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\left(F\left(x_{k-1}\right)-F\left(x_{k}\right)-\left(x_{k-1}-x_{k}\right)F'\left(x_{k}\right)\right)}\end{aligned}

Applying the generalized main value theorem (Taylor-Lagrange's formula) to $ F $ on $ \left[x_{k-1},x_{k}\right], \ k\in\left[\!\left[1,n\right]\!\right] $, there exists some $ \gamma_{k} $ such that : \begin{aligned} F\left(x_{k-1}\right)-F\left(x_{k}\right)-\left(x_{k-1}-x_{k}\right)F'\left(x_{k}\right)&=\frac{\left(x_{k-1}-x_{k}\right)^{2}}{2}F''\left(\gamma_{k}\right)\\ &=\frac{\left(x_{k}-x_{k-1}\right)f'\left(\gamma_{k}\right)}{2n} \end{aligned}

Thus :\begin{aligned} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)}-\int_{0}^{1}{f\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x}&=\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\left(x_{k}-x_{k-1}\right)f'\left(\gamma_{k}\right)}\\ &=\frac{1}{2n}\int_{0}^{1}{f'\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x}+\underset{\overset{n\to +\infty}{}}{\mathcal{o}}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\end{aligned}

(Riemann sums theorem)

Thus : $$\fbox{$\begin{array}{rcl}\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}{f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)}-n\int_{0}^{1}{f\left(x\right)\mathrm{d}x}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\frac{f\left(1\right)-f\left(0\right)}{2}\end{array}$}$$

Now apply this to $ f_{p}:x\mapsto x^{p} $, $ p\in\mathbb{N} \cdot $